# Azure Media Service: Failed authorization policy evaluation

Tags: azure-media-services

I'm using Azure Media Services. I have an encoded asset placed there with Content Key and Asset Delivery Policy. I'm also using the Token restriction.

I am able to stream the video well on localhost but as soon as I deployed the application to the server it stopped streaming and giving an error code: 0x20500006 (of Azure Media Player).

When I checked all the requests I found that there is a request to Key Delivery service with some KID and it returned the following response:

```
<Error>
    <Message>
       Failed authorization policy evaluation.
    </Message>
    <Code>
       Unauthorized
    </Code>
</Error>
```

I am using the HTTPS protocol on the server also tried over HTTP as well but got no response.

Answer (score 0):

I responded to your post on MSDN. Posting on here for visibility.

"There are different reasons for the unauthorized error. It may be due to one of the following reasons:

- Missing authentication header.
- Bad authentication header value.
    -The token has expired.
    -The token contains an invalid signature.
- Policy misconfiguration
- No token in the request

Please double check to make sure your token has not expired. Also, for the Media Services REST request to succeed, the calling user must be a Contributor or Owner role in the Media Services account it is trying to access. For more information, see this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-use-aad-auth-to-access-ams-api#access-control) about Access control."

Comment: I verified all the four points. They are good. Also, the thing is the same code is working good on local but failing on server for the same client machine.

Comment: Also, When I try to use the same URL and Token generated by server on local, it works good.

Comment: can you please tell me if Issuer and Audience of token has anything to do with hosted server URL?

Comment: In my case, the problem happened when the JWT token created without setting an expiration date. However, once the expiry date set, player works with the token!